# A function to remove table from a query using notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following queries:

> insert into tab1 ( id , name , last ) values ( 1 , 's' ,'t')
>   /
>   insert into tab1 ( id , name , last ) values (2 , 'U' ,'t')
>   /
>   insert into tab1 ( id , name , last ) values ( 3 , 'E' ,'t')
>   /
>   INSERT INTO EXAMPLE( ID , NAME, LAST ) values ( 1 , 'EXAMPLE' ,'Y')
>   /
>   insert into tab1 ( id , name , last ) values ( 4 , 'A' ,'t')
>   /

can I find a function or a way in notepad++ to remove the query of table tab1 ?

the desire result is :

> INSERT INTO EXAMPLE( ID , NAME, LAST ) values ( 1 , 'EXAMPLE' ,'Y')
>   /

the rest is deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part is getting rid of the unwanted slashes. The following works on my Notepad++ 5.8.6, assuming the string <kbd>tab1</kbd> is found only in this context (not, say, in a field's content).

1. Identify a character that is not used in the document (let's assume <kbd>@</kbd>).
2. Replace all <kbd>\r\n/</kbd> with <kbd>@</kbd> using extended/escaped search mode.
3. Open the Find dialog and ensure Mark line is checked.
4. Enter <kbd>tab1</kbd> in the find text field and click Find All.
5. Select Search > Bookmark > Delete Bookmarked Lines.
6. Replace all <kbd>@</kbd> with <kbd>\r\n/</kbd> using extended/escaped search mode.